# Yii2 - hasMany with custom query

Tags: yii, yii2

I am trying to create custom query in the **hasMany** function. I am not getting any error, but I am not getting any data from the table inside join statement. What's is wrong?

This is the function:

```
return $this->hasMany(UserKeys::classname(), ['user_id' => 'id'])
            ->select('licences.licenceName, userKeys.*')
            ->from('userKeys')
            ->innerJoin('licences', 'licences.id = userKeys.licence_id');
```

Comment: ->from('userKeys') should not be used, you already define the table above.

Comment: Removed that part, it didn't change anything :/

Comment: take a look at the debug bar, does the SQL query being run look right?

Comment: Check the SQL query string generated by renaming a true column name to false column name. For eg if a table having column 'licenceName', rename that by 'licenceNameX'. You can debug this way too.

Comment: how are the tables related? have you tried the viaTable function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following syntax. It may help you.

```
return $this->hasMany(UserKeys::classname(), ['user_id' => 'id'])
            ->select('licences.licenceName, userKeys.*')
            ->from(['userKeys' => UserKeys::classname()])
            ->viaTable('licences', ['licences.id = userKeys.licence_id']);
```